# Regex match last substring among same substrings in the string

Tags: regex

For example we have a string:
asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_

I need to match this part: /asd/1#s_ or asd/1#s_
How is it possible to do with plain regex?

I've tried negative lookahead like this
But it didn't work

```
\/(?:.(?!\/))?(asd)(\/(([\W\d\w]){1,})|)$
```

it matches this '/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_'
from this 'prefix/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_'
and I need to match '/asd/1#s_' without all preceding /asd/'s

Match should work with plain regex
Without any helper functions of any programming language
https://regexr.com/
I use this site to check if regex matches or not

here's the possible strings:

```
prefix/asd/asd/asd/1#s
prefix/asd/asd/asd/1s#
prefix/asd/asd/asd/s1#
prefix/asd/asd/asd/s#1
prefix/asd/asd/asd/#1s
prefix/asd/asd/asd/#s1
```

and asd part could be replaced with any word like

```
prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1#s
prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1s#
...
```

So I need to match last repeating part with everything to the right
And everything to the right could be character, not character, digit, in any order

A more complicated string example:

prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1s#/ds/dsse/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd

this should match that part:

/a1sd/22$$@!/123/321/asd

Comment: What's your condition? `3-letter/1digit#1-letter_`?

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group `^.*/(asd/[^/]+)` https://regex101.com/r/WPgLIR/1

Comment: @Ava
I need a generic solution which will include:
(letter{1,})/((word character, not word character, number){1,})

Comment: Try `^.*/(\w+/[\w#]+)` https://regex101.com/r/rlYMAI/1/

Comment: `[^\W\d_]+/\w+[^\w/]\w+`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z9NAVJ/1). Or, `(?<=/)[^\W\d_]+/\w+[^\w/]\w+`. Or `(?<=/)[^\W\d_]+/\w+[^\w/]\w+$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird
What is group capture?
It doesn't work here
https://regexr.com/2vckg
And I need a single match

Comment: You are now having ``\`` as directory separator char, so all `/` must be replaced with `\\` or `[\\/]`. And use raw string literals. It seems you are testing regex online against regular string literals, and not actual texts.

Comment: is "asd" a constant or is it just any series of letters?

Comment: @ArtyDev which programming language are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian any series of letters and possible number after the first letter

Comment: @Ava it will be used with nginx

Comment: That is a different example string. What is the language and what should exactly be matched?

Comment: @Arty does only the last part start with a digit? or does it always contain a hash? or is each part basically "anything"

Comment: @Thefourthbird wrong link, sorry
Here it is
regexr.com/5av4b

Comment: @Bohemian
added possible strings to a description

Comment: @ArtyDev so  just regex replace `\basd\b` with `a1sd`  then?

Comment: @Bohemian
I don't need a replacement. 
I showed what repeatable parts could be. 
And I need to match the last repeatable part with everything to the right

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
updated description
maybe with more examples it'll be more clear

Comment: @ArtyDev just letting you know that I still don’t understand what you want, and I suspect I am not alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This works in python.

```py
import re

reg = re.compile(r"\/[a-z]{1,}\/\d+[#a-z_]{1,}")
s = "asd/asd/asd/asd/1#s_"

print(reg.findall(s))
# ['/asd/1#s_']
```

**Update:**

Since the question lacks clarity, this only works with the given order and hence, I suppose any other combination simply fails.

**Edits:**

New Regex

```
reg = r"\/\w+(\/\w*\d+\W*)*(\/\d+\w*\W*)*(\/\d+\W*\w*)*(\/\w*\W*\d+)*(\/\W*\d+\w*)*(\/\W*\w*\d+)*$"
```

Comment: Updated description with more clarification

Comment: @ArtyDev what do you mean by last repeating part? Your last example did not follow that. I'm really sorry but it's still unclear. You can try posting with some actual dataset.

Comment: We have a part (substring) in the string. Let it be a1sd. This part is repeating in the string. prefix/a1sd/a1sd/a1sd/1#s/321/##/sss. Here it's repeating 3 times, and I need to match the last repeating with everything to the right. It will be a1sd/1#s/321/##/sss

Comment: I updated my answer @ArtyDev . Let me know if that works.

Comment: In [regexr](https://www.regexr.com/) don't forget to use multiline flag if you're matching more than one url in different lines.